# Can't update useform field with api call, getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

What i want to do :
Fill my form fields with fetched API DATA and prefill the fields with the corresponding item when the page is rendered.

My issue is simple :
I have an API call from my DB, i put it in my state.
But i can't figure out how to se the data in field AFTER my api call is done, because i got "undefined"

I've tried soem stuff with setValues of useForm but i still can't make it work.

Here is my code :

```
const preloadedValues = {
    title: drawingData && drawingData[0].title,
    imageLink: drawingData && drawingData[0].imageLink,
  };

  const {
    register,
    reset,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ defaultValues: preloadedValues });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOneDrawingData() {
      const data = await fetchOneDrawing(id);
      setDrawingData(data);
      reset(data);
    }
    fetchOneDrawingData();
  }, []);
```

Here is an example of my form field (bootstrap)

```
<Form.Group className='mb-3'>
          <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            placeholder='Drawing title'
            type='text'
            name='title'
            ref={register}
            {...register('title', {
              required: 'Merci de spécifier un titre',
            })}
          />
        </Form.Group>
```

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Please share of these two functions `setDrawingData(data);reset(data);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i solved it with setValues !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOneDrawingData() {
      const data = await fetchOneDrawing(id);
      setDrawingData(data);
      reset(data[0]);
    }
    fetchOneDrawingData();
  }, [reset]);
```